# Detect inAppBrowser in Jquery/PHP

Tags: php, jquery, cordova, inappbrowser

I am using an Phonegap Application which will open webapp link inside the browser.
I need to detect whether the webapp is accessed from Mobile app or from inappbrowser in PhoneGap Application.

Much Appreciated,

Comment: Ding! Ding! Ding! Google had a winner - http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I checked the above url , and found no documentation on how to use that js.

Comment: The documentation is in the text files themselves. Most are functions that will return true if a mobile browser is detected.